# Matlab/Simulink Data Store Memory Error: "Simulink does not have enough information to determine output sizes for this block"

Tags: matlab, constants, simulink

I have got a problem with matlabs simulink and i am already struggling for more than a hour on this simple task, but i do not know what is wrong.
i have a matlab function (calc_fft) and i have a constant (targetFrequency). I do not want to write this constant in the function block. instead i want it in a "data store memory" block.

In the picture below, you can see my setup/configuration.
I just want one number inside this data store memory block, for example 440.

[image: problem]

inside the matlab function block, there is something like this

```
function [y,mx,amp] = fcn(u)
    global targetFrequency;
    target = targetFrequency;
...
```

Every time i try to run the model, the error which is visible in the picture below is shown.

[image: error]

what am i doing wrong? any suggestions?

Comment: `targetFrequency` doesn't seem to be initialized properly. In that little code snippet, you define it `global` and then *immediately* use it, before initializing it to something. You also don't seem to specify its size in the MATLAB function (its set to `-1`) or in the data story (same).

Comment: thanks for the answer - if figured it out now, the problem was, that i was stripping an array in this function ( array(0:n) ), i think 0 is not a feasible index for an array, because i found out matlab arrays start with the index 1. but nevertheless it worked without the "data storage memory" with the 0 as index - i am wondering why. the initial value of the global variable is set in the "block parameters"-dialog, and i think "-1" means, that the size of the value is inherited.